# Why might DVI output be toggled on/off when VGA cable is plugged/unplugged?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, vga, dvi, nvidia-geforce

I'm able to connect a Windows 10 box with an NVIDIA GeForce 9400 GT card using the DVI output to send 1080p at 60Hz to an HDMI input on an LG TV model number 43UM6910PUA. The LG supports this resolution and at first glance everything seems to work fine with these settings. **However**, when I unplug the VGA cable from the NVIDIA card, the DVI output stops. And when I plug the VGA cable back into the NVIDIA card, the DVI output resumes. The DIV output appears to be toggled by the presence/absence of the VGA cable. What could be causing this? Might Windows 10 be assuming that the LG TV is a secondary display, and turning off the signal to the secondary display when the primary display is unplugged, as some sort of convenience or power saving feature? Or is something else happening here? In any case, how do I disable this behavior? I'd like to eliminate the VGA display from this setup, and use the LG as the primary display for the Windows 10 box. (I'm able to configure the LG as the primary display, but the issue described above persists.)

Comment: Are you plugging this cable 'hot', ie while the computer is running? VGA is not hot-swappable & DVI only in certain circumstances.

Comment: Plugging/unplugging VGA can theoretically damage connected equipment, although I've never observed this in practice. In this case, I'm booting with the VGA unplugged, and observing that the DVI output is disabled. Then, for troubleshooting purposes, I'm plugging in the VGA cable, and the DVI output is immediately enabled. Unplug the VGA again, and the DVI output is immediately disabled.

Comment: I'm wanting to use the DVI output without using the VGA output at all. I've previously used the DVI output without the VGA output, on the exact same card, and that worked on Debian and I think on Windows 7 as well. The changes now are that I'm running Windows 10 and sending the DVI output to an HDMI input on a new display. My old DVI display failed, so I'm not able to test with that.

Comment: After rolling back to an older NVIDIA driver, and doing some additional troubleshooting, I'm able to have the LG come up as the primary display after reboot, but only when the VGA output is connected **and** the VGA display has power. The VGA display does **not** need to be turned on! If I unplug the power from the VGA display, and reboot, then the LG does **not** come up as the primary display. I'm considering buying (or making) a VGA dummy plug. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Your video card seems to support only 1 primary monitor which has to be on the other [port](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/103775/help-with-dual-monitor-setup-9400gt/), try switching the ports for each monitor. Sometimes you can not use both the analog VGA and digital DVI port at the same time. Windows 7 seems to have this problem for a lot of [people](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6cbb332e-a44d-4a32-a0b9-8772397237de/nvedia-gforce-9400gt-is-not-supported-by-windows-7?forum=w7itprohardware).

Sometimes its possible to make both channels analog from the Nvidia Settings panel.

Try lowering the resolution and making it the same for both monitors.

Comment: I'm currently able to use the VGA and DVI simultaneously, with independent resolutions for each display.In the past, I've been able to use the DVI output by itself, when running Debian and I think Windows 7, but not when running Windows 10 on the exact same hardware. I've tried multiple resolutions, with no effect.

Comment: When I've set the DVI output to be primary, the DVI output is then immediately disabled. To recover, I have to unplug the DVI so the display defaults back to VGA, then delete the registry keys where Windows has saved the monitor settings. After that, I'm able to reboot and use both displays again, but I'm unable to use only the DVI.

Comment: What is your windows version? Does your Nvidia card have settings for 2 monitors and 1 monitor? I have optimized performance for 1 monitor. Also what is your windows edition, pro, home or other? Can you try using an Ubuntu live USB to check if the problem is hardware based or software based. It should be software based.

Comment: The issue occurs on Windows 10 Home, but not on Windows 7 or Debian, so definitely software related. The NVIDIA card supports two monitors.

Comment: I have had a lot of problems with the home and pro versions. Can you please try to install the net frameworks 4.5 and 4.8, also visual redistributable 2005, 2008, 2012, 2015, both x32bit and x64bit. Your video card is old, perhaps one of these can solve the problem.